# Zapier change Podio field value

Tags: trello, podio, zapier

I'm setting up Zapier to make Trello and Podio work together for some project management. However, I can't find a possibility to change/update a Podio field value (ex 'Idea' -> 'Decided') from a trigger in Trello. Have any of you guys/gals figured out how to change a field value?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunely Zapier doesn't support an "update item" podio action currently.

You could however do this via the podio API using importer, having trello write the data somewhere (maybe to a Google Sheet via the zapier integration) and overwrite the podio items that have changed by importing that data, using a specific id field to deduce against

Comment: Please, enhance your answer by adding more info about solution